# Good database client (MS SQL Server) with auto-complete, small memory foot-print and free?

Tags: sql-server, database, client, squirrel-sql

Any sugestions?

Currently I'm using Squirell but it consumes quiet a bit of memory... I just use the sql client to run some queries and get the result but i absolutely need auto-complete of tables, columns, etc

Comment: checkout [QueryCommander](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/QueryCommander.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Management Studio Express (intellisense works only on Sql Server 2008)

Answer (score 2):

RedGate who makes SQLCompare has a tool called SQL Prompt that provides:

- Intelligent code completion for fast, accurate script building
- Script layout for easy code readability
- Cross-database and linked-server query support
- Integrates with SSMS, SSMS Express, Query Analyzer and Visual Studio
- Keyword formatting, code snippet integration, column picker and many more features

I have only tried the 14-day free trial and it was really nice to use. I mostly work in Query Analyser and it worked great there.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm

Nice demonstration video :
http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/video.htm